# Aborted request @import https://fonts.googleapis

Tags: css, google-font-api

When I try loading some standard fonts using googleapis 
 `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Abhaya+Libre|Tahoma);`

My request fails 
(GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Abhaya+Libre|Tahoma net::ERR_ABORTED).
 This only happens if I include fonts like "Verdana" or "Tahoma".
Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to avoid it?

https://jsfiddle.net/232ptdh2/

Clear cache before loading the fiddle in order to avoid using cached fonts.
Fonts othen then some specific standards, like before mentioned Takoma and Verdana seem to be working fine